# ISO timestamp for Docker dates

Tags: linux, bash, docker, date, timestamp

The date printed by Docker is not parseable by `date`. For example, when I run `date --date=$(docker image ls --no-trunc --format '{{.CreatedAt}}' | head -n 1)`, date complains: `date: invalid date ‘2019-07-31 17:26:31 -0500 CDT’`

Is there a way to get `docker` to write an ISO-compliant date timestamp? If not, how can I safely transform the date printed by `docker` into an ISO timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date command is fairly liberal in accepting various inputs. However, the trailing timezone in both an offset and a string appears to be throwing it off. You can just cut that part off with the `cut` command:

```
date --date="$(docker image ls --no-trunc --format '{{.CreatedAt}}' | \
  head -n 1 | cut -f1-3 -d' ')"
```